# ng-repeat or ng-options How can I automatically select the last row in a table ?

Tags: angularjs

How I can I automatically select the last row in a table 
ng-repeat="unit in selectedOrder.products"    using something like select by track by $index == desc  or alternatively ng-options

```
   <div class="search" ng-show="selectedOrder">
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                <tr><th>Item</th><th>Name</th><th>ValueToday</th></tr>
                <tr ng-repeat="unit in selectedOrder.products">
                    <td><img ng-  src="http:images/thumbnails/{{unit.shortname}}_tn.jpg" width=40 height=40
             alt="{{ unit.shortname | limitTo: 18}} Photo"></td>
                    <td>{{unit.name | limitTo:18 }}</td>
                    <td>{{unit.valuetoday| currency:"£"}} </td>
                </tr>
                 </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

In ng-repeat you can use the `$last` special variable to apply something only if it's the last element. see: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

you can use it as a condition for anything you want to do in the tag. like

```
<img class="{{$last ? 'selected'}}" ng-class="{'selected': $last}" ng-if="$last" ....>
```

or however you like (these are just examples)

Always keep in mind though that using angular means that you have to edit your model to apply changes to your view, so if you want to have an element selected you have to do something to your model so that the element contains a value that makes it selected and then your view should reflect this.
For example in your controller you can check which element is the last in your ng-repeat array and add a `selected` variable, then in your view do something to make it look like your element is selected (for example: `ng-class="{'selected': element.selected}"`) otherwise, by working on the view only you can make it look like the element is selected using `$last` but it won't be really selected in your model

In fact In ng-options (so we are talking about a select) you have to change your model in order to reflect your choice. So for example if your select has an attribute like this: `ng-model="selected"` then in your controller you set the `$scope.selected` variable to the last element of the array containing the values for your `ng-options`

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="search" ng-show="selectedOrder">
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                <tr><th>Item</th><th>Name</th><th>ValueToday</th></tr>
                <tr ng-repeat="unit in selectedOrder.products" ng-if="$last">
                    <td><img ng-  src="http:images/thumbnails/{{unit.shortname}}_tn.jpg" width=40 height=40
             alt="{{ unit.shortname | limitTo: 18}} Photo"></td>
                    <td>{{unit.name | limitTo:18 }}</td>
                    <td>{{unit.valuetoday| currency:"£"}} </td>
                </tr>
                 </table>
```

will give you only the last row selected

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like `ng-if="$index == $last"`

Comment: last is a boolean, not an integer https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat